# Send CTRL SHIFT LETTER in Linux TTY console with loadkeys / keymappings

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I am trying to achieve keybindings like <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to work in Linux tty console (Arch Linux) for usage in editors. For this, the only solution seems to be custom keymapping with `loadkeys`.

Here's how I successfully did that with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>:

```
control shift keycode 105 = F204
string F204 = "\033[1;6D"
```

For <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, it should be

```
# legend: 107 is ascii for k, 75 is ascii for K, 37 is keycode for k, u means unicode, 6 means ctrl shift, 2 means shift
control shift keycode 37 = F205
string F205 = "\033[107;6u"
```

([source](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/))
But this only prints `7;6u` when I press it.
`107;2u`, `75;6u`, `75;2u` also did not send ctrlshiftK. [Keymaps manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/keymaps) did not help me out either.

I also tried `tmux` inside an `fbterm` framebuffer where it then does not print `7;6u` but simply does not do anything.

How does one achieve this?

Comment: You are right, thanks @Quasímodo. It was actually an editor issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keybinding works as described